# Best way to monitor USB drive insertion and set up Wi-Fi in Android

Tags: android, usb-drive

I'm running stock Android KitKat on a custom board.  I'd like to be able to detect when a USB drive is inserted, read a text file from the drive, and then change Wi-Fi settings based on the contents of the file.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with a shell script; since I have never written an Android app before I think that would be the quickest way.  However I'm new to Android, and I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want via a shell script.  I've been able to get a simple script to run automatically at boot, but when I insert the USB drive nothing shows up in /dev.

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but can someone nudge me in the right direction?  Is this doable via a shell script, or should I bite the bullet and download and learn the Android SDK?

Thanks

Marlon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to detect USB device plug or unplug behaviours in shell script, but this method is unreliable and ugly. Meanwhile, how can you set-up the Wi-Fi after USB device attach in your shell script? The preferable way to do in app layer is setting up a `BroadcastReceiver` to detect the event, and to do different actions basic on different events. In Android app, you can do like this.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED)) {
                // TODO: handle accessory attache action
            } else if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED)) {
                // TODO: handle accessory detach action
            } else if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
                // TODO: handle device attache action
            } else if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
                // TODO: handle device detach action
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED);
    intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
    intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: I believe it might be possible to do via a script, and set up wifi using wpa_cli, but this seems like the better solution.  Decided to bite the bullet and learn how to write an Android app.  I used this code and it is working, thanks.

Comment: In theory it can be done as you said. but at the end it will mess up the wifi state with android framework, finally the wifi might not work properly when the use try to do the settings.